# RecyclerView doesn't delete items - although list has correct item number

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a strange case with recyclerView (with GridLayoutManager).
When I delete an Item and refresh it with (notifyItemRemoved and notifyItemRangeChanged/notifyDataSetChanged) it does not remove the item but kind of marks it for delete (it's kind of greyed out). If the item isn't last, so it is kind of deleted, but not really - it's just under other item and not visible (if I add an additional view to this Item - you can see it's there), but if it is last you can see it greyed out.

It's not my first time working with recyclerView and I haven't encountered it before, but it first time with GridLayoutManager, so it might be the reason why.

I have debugged the code, and can clearly see that the List of items contains the correct items (4) after deleting the 5th in the onBindViewHolder when it recreates the recyclerView after the refresh.

Here is the delete functionality when a marked Icon clicked, it gets an X icon and dialog appears.

```
private class DeleteMessageDialog extends MessageDialog {
    List<Item> expenses;

    public DeleteMessageDialog(String message, List<Item> expenses) {
        super(DELETE_CATEGORY, WARNING, message, activity);
        this.expenses = expenses;
    }

    @Override
    protected void okPressed() {
        DataHelper.getDataHelper(activity).removeItems(expenses);
        viewBuilder.refreshItems(DELETE_ITEM);
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

The refresh method (I have hardcoded the 4 - just as quick and dirty solution as before I had notifyDataSetChanged) and changed the values according to Phuc comment:

```
public void refreshItems(Enums.Action action) {
    dataHelper.setListOfCategoryItems();
    List<Category> categoryItems = Utils.getCategoryItems(Utils.NO_PARENT_PREDICATE);
    categoryItemAdapter.updateData(categoryItems);
    MonthlyStatistics statistics = DataHelper.getDataHelper(activity).getMonthlyStatistics(Utils.getCurrentDate(PAY));
    statBuilder.populateStatistics(statistics.getStatistics().get(category));
    if (action == ADD_ITEM)
    {
        activity.moveToMainPage();
        categoryItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    if (action == DELETE_ITEM)
    {
        categoryItemAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(4);
        categoryItemAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(4, 1);
    }

}
```

The updateData method

```
public void updateData(List<Category> categoryItems) {
    this.categoryItems.clear();
    this.categoryItems.addAll(categoryItems);
    this.parentsAndChildren.clear();
    this.parentsAndChildren.putAll(getChildrenAndParents(categoryItems));
}
```

[image]

In debug mode the onBindViewHolder - can see that there are only correct 4 items left
[image]

After all is finished that's the result:

[image]

If I delete the 3rd item (not the last) the result looks like that:

[image]

I have searched all the internet, and could not find a solution, so I hope posting here will help.
Appreciate all the answers.
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
As Kamal Nayan suggested if creating the adapter again and putting it inside recyclerView does work, but I'm pretty sure there is a better solution, and would appreciate if someone will find it.

Comment: Tried to set the adapter again?

Comment: @KamalNayan I was avoiding this solution, but yes, setting the adapter again works, but I'm pretty sure it's not the correct way of doing it, as we do have all the notify methods to do just that. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: If you'd like to share a demo for that so we can have a look thoroughly as this is a strange behavior

Comment: @Zain It is pretty much a demo with the screenshots. The screenshots are in the right order.
After clicking on some icon, the delete message appears. By clicking DELETE button, that the result you see..

Answer (score 0):

You have misused the functionality of notifyItemRemoved and notifyRangeChanged. In the documentation:

> notifyItemRemoved(int position)

with position is the item's position that was removed. In your case, you're deleting the 5th item, so you should pass 4, instead of 5.

> notifyRangeChanged(int positionStart, itemCount)

- positionStart: Position of the first item that has changed
- itemCount: Number of items that have changed

I dont think this method is necessary if you already called `notifyItemRemoved()`, but you should pass 4 for the positionStart and 1 for itemCount because you only change the 5th item.

**EDIT**: I think I see another problem in your code. Whenever you delete an item, you clear the old list then pass a new list to the adapter. Because the previous list attached to the adapter has been delete and a new one is attached, your call to `notifyItemRemoved()` doesn't make sense since in the new list, nothing has changed. That leads to the unexpected recycler view behavior you're facing. My proposed solution is you modify the list in your adapter instead of creating new ones each time deleting. For example declare a method `deleteItem(int position)` in your adapter:

```
public void deleteItem(int position){
     yourList.remove(position);
     notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Comment: You are correct about the misuse of those 2 methods, thanks. I fixed that, Unfortunately it does not solve my problem. 

The solution that Kamal suggested does work, but I'm pretty sure it isn't a proper way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, it is not necessary to set a new adapter. Please take a look at my edited answer

Comment: Although I think that the List is the same list (as I add items from the list I pass to the state list), I did what you suggested (deleted the item explicitly from the list without adding the items from other list), and still got the same result.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you maybe right. But at least my way will cut off the whole `clear()` and `addAll()`. About the problem, so strange. Did you change the GridLayout to another layout managers (ie: LinearLayoutManager), did the problem still exist?

Comment: yes, I have changed it now to Linear. Same problem.
Seems like magic to me.
Right now the only solution that works, is to reload the adapter, which I'm trying to avoid.